# sudo kill: Operation not permitted over SSH

Tags: shell-script, sudo, kill

Using `heredoc` to execute multi-line commands on a remote machine.
Trying to get pid of a server to kill that server located in the remote machine

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

HOST_IP="10.180.5.23"
read -p "For HOST RESTART press 1" num
if [ "$num" == "1" ]
then
    ssh -t -t $HOST_IP << 'EOSSH'
    line=$(pgrep -f host_server1)
    echo $line
    arr=($line)
    sudo kill -9 "${arr[1]}"
EOSSH 
fi
```

Error :   kill: (15015) - Operation not permitted

Comment: `kill $line` doesn't work ?

Comment: Does the `kill` work when you execute it manually, rather than as part of the script?
Also, I'd recommend against `kill -9`. Use a normal `kill`. `kill -9` is the last resort, because it doesn't allow a clean shutdown of the process. `kill -9` is probably the most well known bad practice in systems administration.

Comment: Can you start an interactive shell on the remote machine?  If so, try running the commands one at a time to see the output of each, and work out which one is misbehaving.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Tried all the commands individually on those machines and they run smoothly

Comment: @Score_Under Yes `kill` is working good

Comment: Is it always the same process id (15015) that appears in the error message, or a different one each time?  Are you the only user on the remote machine?

Comment: [Bash arrays are zero-based](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays), so `${arr[1]}` gives the second member of the array (or nothing if there was only one result).  How many of the matching processes do you want to kill?

Comment: @JigglyNaga The process id is different every time

Comment: @JigglyNaga arr contains 2 process ids
But i want to kill the second one .Thus `${arr[1]}`

Comment: Always the second one?  (pids are assigned in order but eventually loop round.)  Please [edit the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/298297/edit) to show the full output from running the script, including the results of the `echo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `pgrep` it is highly likely that you also have `pkill`.

Using `pgrep` and then `kill` introduces a theoretical race condition. Using `pkill` removes the race condition (from the script), and also avoids having to use a variable to hold the PIDs:

```
ssh -t -t "$HOST_IP" pkill -f host_server1
```

or, if you wanted to send the `KILL` signal:

```
ssh -t -t "$HOST_IP" pkill -KILL -f host_server1
```

Note that with `-f`, `pgrep` and `pkill` will match the pattern against the whole command line, not just the process name.

With `-n` and `-o`, the newest or the oldest (respectively) of the matching processes will be affected. Thus, if you want to `KILL` the newest `host_server1` and nothing else:

```
ssh -t -t "$HOST_IP" pkill -KILL -n -f host_server1
```